# Springboot disable selected prometheus metrics

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer, prometheus-java

I am using springboot gateway 2.0.4.RELEASE.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

After adding this dependency, it is exposing all metrics to prometheus endpoint.

I want to disable some of the metrics from exposing through **/actuator/prometheus** endpoint.

Let's say I want to disable

1. gateway_requests_seconds_count
2. gateway_requests_seconds_sum
3. gateway_requests_seconds_max

Does anyone know how can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Alpesh

Comment: This should be possible with [Meter filters](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_meter_filters).